# "Group By" is Not Grouping As Expected

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've created the following query with the intention to segregate the information of a database by date and 30 min time buckets.

It may look complicated but it's just a date column, a time bucket column, a bunch of columns that classify the information as needed and four counts.

```
SELECT
    CAST("oo"."created" AS DATE) AS "date",
    
    TO_CHAR(
        DATEADD(
            MINUTE,
            CAST(
                FLOOR(
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', "oo"."created") / CAST(30 AS DECIMAL)
                ) * 30 AS INTEGER
            ),
            '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
        ),
        'HH24:MI'
    ) AS "time_bucket",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."decision_date" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN NOT("dodb"."precise_type" = 'HODN' OR "dodb"."precise_type" = 'HOD') THEN NULL
        WHEN DATEDIFF(SECONDS, "oo"."decision_date", "ooa"."created") <= 3 THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, "oo"."created", "ooa"."created") <= 3 THEN 'IN'
                ELSE 'OUT'
            END
        ELSE NULL
    END AS "sla",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."product_name" = 'ASSIST' THEN 'API'
        WHEN "oo"."product_name" = 'BUSINESS' THEN 'B2B'
        WHEN "oard"."logic_name" = 'TRAVEL AND HOTELS Hold' THEN 'T&H'
        WHEN "pccar"."amount" >= 1000 THEN 'H$D'
        WHEN "oard"."logic_name" ILIKE '%UYO%' THEN 'UYO'
        WHEN "oo"."product_name" = 'MALL' THEN 'MALL'
        WHEN "pccar"."brand_code" = 'BUCKS' THEN 'BUX'
        ELSE 'ALL'
    END AS "queue",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."decision_date" IS NULL AND "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN 'WAITING REPLY'
        ELSE 'DECISIONED'
    END AS "status",
    
    CASE
        WHEN ("oo"."decision_date" IS NOT NULL AND "ooa"."created" IS NULL) THEN 'SYSTEM'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" IS NOT NULL THEN 'AGENT'
        WHEN ("dodb"."precise_type" = 'HOD' OR "dodb"."precise_type" = 'HODN') THEN 'AGENT'
        ELSE 'SYSTEM'
    END AS "decider",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN ("dodb"."precise_type" = 'HOD' OR "dodb"."precise_type" = 'HODN') THEN 'EXPECTED'
        ELSE 'UNEXPECTED'
    END AS "planned",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."decision_date" IS NULL THEN 'WR'
        WHEN "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN '1D: SYSTEM'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(SECONDS, "oo"."decision_date", "ooa"."created") <= 3 THEN '1D: AGENT'
        ELSE 'ND: AGENT'
    END AS "touch",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "ooa"."username" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@A.com{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'A'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@b.com{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'B'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@u.com.do{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'U'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@c.com{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'C'
        ELSE '@OTHER'
    END AS "domain",

    COUNT("oo"."id") AS "oo.count",

    COUNT(DISTINCT "oo"."id") AS "oo.dcount",

    COUNT("ooa"."id") AS "ooa.count",

    COUNT(DISTINCT "ooa"."id") AS "ooa.dcount"

FROM
    "TAB1"."1" "OO"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "TAB1"."A" "PCCAR" ON "OO"."O" = "PCCAR"."auth_token"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "TAB1"."B" "OARD" ON "OO"."id" = "OARD"."riskprovider_order_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "TAB1"."C" "OOA" ON "OO"."id" = "OOA"."order_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "TAB1"."D" "DROD" ON "OO"."id" = "DROD"."order_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "TAB1"."E" "DODB" ON "DROD"."F" = "DODB"."id"

WHERE
    ("OO"."created" >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) AS DATE))
    AND ("OO"."created" < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) AS DATE))

GROUP BY
    CAST("oo"."created" AS DATE) AS "date ",
    
    TO_CHAR(
        DATEADD(
            MINUTE,
            CAST(
                FLOOR(
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '1000-01-01 00:00:00', "oo"."created") / CAST(30 AS DECIMAL)
                ) * 30 AS INTEGER
            ),
            '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
        ),
        'HH24:MI'
    ) AS "time_bucket ",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."decision_date" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN NOT("dodb"."precise_type" = 'HODN' OR "dodb"."precise_type" = 'HOD') THEN NULL
        WHEN DATEDIFF(SECONDS, "oo"."decision_date", "ooa"."created") <= 3 THEN 
            CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, "oo"."created", "ooa"."created") <= 3 THEN 'IN'
                ELSE 'OUT'
            END
        ELSE NULL
    END AS "sla ",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."product_name" = 'ASSIST' THEN 'API'
        WHEN "oo"."product_name" = 'BUSINESS' THEN 'B2B'
        WHEN "oard"."logic_name" = 'TRAVEL AND HOTELS Hold' THEN 'T&H'
        WHEN "pccar"."amount" >= 1000 THEN 'H$D'
        WHEN "oard"."logic_name" ILIKE '%UYO%' THEN 'UYO'
        WHEN "oo"."product_name" = 'MALL' THEN 'MALL'
        WHEN "pccar"."brand_code" = 'BUCKS' THEN 'BUX'
        ELSE 'ALL'
    END AS "queue",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."decision_date" IS NULL AND "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN 'WAITING REPLY'
        ELSE 'DECISIONED'
    END AS "status",
    
    CASE
        WHEN ("oo"."decision_date" IS NOT NULL AND "ooa"."created" IS NULL) THEN 'SYSTEM'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" IS NOT NULL THEN 'AGENT'
        WHEN ("dodb"."precise_type" = 'HOD' OR "dodb"."precise_type" = 'HODN') THEN 'AGENT'
        ELSE 'SYSTEM'
    END AS "decider",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN ("dodb"."precise_type" = 'HOD' OR "dodb"."precise_type" = 'HODN') THEN 'EXPECTED'
        ELSE 'UNEXPECTED'
    END AS "planned",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "oo"."decision_date" IS NULL THEN 'WR'
        WHEN "ooa"."created" IS NULL THEN '1D: SYSTEM'
        WHEN DATEDIFF(SECONDS, "oo"."decision_date", "ooa"."created") <= 3 THEN '1D: AGENT'
        ELSE 'ND: AGENT'
    END AS "touch",
    
    CASE
        WHEN "ooa"."username" IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@A.com{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'A'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@b.com{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'B'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@u.com.do{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'U'
        WHEN "ooa"."username" LIKE '%@c.com{MANAGEMENT}' THEN 'C'
        ELSE '@OTHER'
    END AS "domain"
```

Here is a sample of the result:

| date | time_bucket | sla | queue | status | decider | planned | touch | domain | oo.count | oo.dcount | ooa.count | ooa.dcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | ALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | ALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | ALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | ALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

It's not aggregating all records as I was hoping. I was hoping to get this:

| date | time_bucket | sla | queue | status | decider | planned | touch | domain | oo.count | oo.dcount | ooa.count | ooa.dcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | ALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 2024-03-11 | 01:30 | IN | MALL | DECISIONED | AGENT | EXPECTED | 1D: AGENT | B | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

While investigating a solution on my own, I found out that the most common mistake is not using the correct terms on the "Group By" clause. I don't think that's my problem here since I'm using basically the same "Select" and "Group By" clause.

I'm kinda lost, I started to believe it was due to the order of execution since I have no other solution.

Comment: That  code won't run (`AS` terms in the `GROUP BY` clause, ends with a `,`). If you want us to debug your code, at least include the actual code.  Better still , write a [mre] that demonstrates the behaviour (by incrementally cutting out code that isn't causing the problem) [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to change it a bit to hide sensitive information. Code is now updated.

Comment: You need to ensure that the code you post generates the problem you've described. It still doesn't even run. You also need to actually read both [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. When people have to scroll to read a query, many turn away.

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN … END AS A,
  CASE WHEN … END AS B,
  count(1)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

`1, 2` here means the column number within the select statement — which in this case queried column A, B.